Cannot upgrade 20.04 KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-minimal'"
I am trying to upgrade an older server from 20.04 to 22.04. But when I run sudo do-release-upgrade I get the following error
KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-minimal'" 

This is the full error
A fatal error occurred 

Please report this as a bug and include the files 
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in 
your report. The upgrade has aborted. 
Your original sources.list was saved in 
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade. 

Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 299, in 
__getitem__ 
rawpkg = self._cache[key] 

KeyError: 'ubuntu-minimal' 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 


Traceback (most recent call last): 

File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-w3ptvu69/jammy", line 8, in 
<module> 
sys.exit(main()) 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-w3ptvu69/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", 
line 241, in main 
if app.run(): 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-w3ptvu69/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", 
line 2042, in run 
return self.fullUpgrade() 

File 
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-w3ptvu69/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", 
line 1913, in fullUpgrade 
if not self.cache.anyVersionDownloadable(self.cache[pkg]): 

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 301, in 
__getitem__ 
raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key) 

KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'ubuntu-minimal'" 

If I run apt show ubuntu-minimal before the upgrade it shows me that it exists. But if I run it after the failed upgrade it is suddenly gone. So I think there is a bug in the sources.list file in the upgrade.
Edit: Ok I think I am getting closer. It seems that it disables all of my sources as they are from hetzner? Do I need to use another mirror to be able to upgrade?!
This is after I try to upgrade
# deb https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/packages focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


# deb https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security main restricted # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security main restricted
# deb https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security universe # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security universe
# deb https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy
# deb-src https://mirror.hetzner.com/ubuntu/security focal-security multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe


I have tried running sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* to no effect

It seems that the package exists before I run the do-release-upgrade command, but it isn't part of the sources.list after the update program replaces it

This may not be a full answer, but it was too long for a comment.
do-release-upgrade will disable all non-official repos during the upgrade.
I would not recommend upgrading to a new release when using an OS image in the cloud.
It's better to recycle your instance by setting up your applications on a new and fresh installation of the newer Ubuntu version.
There are many reasons for this, but OTOH, these are a couple of ones:

If the upgrade fails, you have no option to revert it, which can cause your server to break and, in the worst case, make it inaccessible. (This is not Ubuntu-specific but more of a general point.)
If your application is not properly supported on the new version, you may not be able to get a new installation with an old OS version, as your hosting provider may have removed that option.
If, instead, you use a new installation, your old server is still up, and you can revert all your settings and use the old installation until you fix the incompatibilities in your application.
do-release-upgrade does not have proper support on custom installations. Since Hetzner is using its own repos instead of an official mirror, you will face the exact issues you are facing as they will be disabled during the upgrade.


I would highly recommend against going through this route, but you can update your source list to use the official Ubuntu repositories and then run the upgrade. However, this can seriously break your server, as Hetzner may have customized some repositories to work with their own setup.

I agree that this indeed sounds like the correct way to go. The reason I am trying my hardest to get it to upgrade is because we have jenkins set up on the server, and it will take a lot of time to set it all up from scratch again :/ But it sounds like I have no way around it and have to start over sadly.
